# find gcd of multiple user inputted values using C

Tags: c, recursion, greatest-common-divisor

```
#include <stdio.h>
int gcd()
{
int i,j,rem;
printf("Enter two integers: ");
scanf("%d%d",&i,&j);
while (i !=0)
{
    rem = j % i;
    j=i;
    i=rem;
} 
 printf("Greatest common denominator is %d\n",j);
}
int main()
{    

    gcd();
    return 0;
}
```

I am learning C using  "C programming a modern approach 2nd edition."
One of the exercises I had  to create a function that takes in two numbers from  a user
and returns the gcd,  I would like to be able to pass in multiple numbers but I don't know how to achieve this using C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend passing the numbers as an array of `int` and then applying the gcd algorithm on it recursively (preferably).

```
int gcd(int *array, int n)
{
    if(n == 0)
    {
        //find gcd using while loop of array[n] and array[n + 1]. store in result.
        return result;
    }
    return gcd(int *a, n -1);
}
```

Comment: I have been learning C for a week, coming from python so I understand that recursion will work, I am unclear how to do this using C.

Comment: I haven't tried this code yet but this is the essence of what you're looking for. You'll probably have to call the gcd function with second parameter as one less than the count of the number of elements in the array.

Comment: How do I take an unknown amount of user inputted numbers and assign them to positions in the array?

Comment: You may dynamically expand the array at runtime using `realloc()` function.
I presume you're acquainted with `malloc()`?
`realloc()` works in a similar fashion but copies old data to new memory location (if needed) if the array already contained data before hand.

Comment: You may write:
int *array=NULL, arraysize=0;
while(user wishes to input)
    array = (int *) realloc(array, ++arraysize);

Comment: thanks, that is the bit that I was finding hard,  is it also possible to use va_list with user input?

Comment: I believe not. Variable argument lists are used when defining functions. So even if you define a gcd function which takes va_list as a parameter, you can't possibly call it with varying number of arguments at the runtime. Using an int array is your best bet.

Comment: I discovered va_lists trying to find a solution to my problem, I was not sure if I could apply it. Thanks again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48998/discussion-between-reza-safiyat-and-padraic-cunningham)